# HTML/CSS Content height of biggest

Tags: html, css

I would like to fix the gaps created by different content sizes in my containers.

http://ctrlv.cz/85Mm
http://ctrlv.cz/YBpa

```
article {
    margin-top: 100px;
    vertical-align: central;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 29%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: Set a min-height on each of the boxes that you are sure will be sufficient for even the largest box:

```
.box {
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

Option 2: Use javascript to get the greatest height of any box, and set each box to have that height.

```
var maxBoxHeight = 0;

$('.box').each(function(){
  var height = $(this).height();

  if(height > maxBoxHeight) {
    maxBoxHeight = height;
  }  
});

$('.box').css({'height', maxBoxHeight + 'px' });
```

Comment: great thanks the first option works but I would like to use that jq and it keeps saying there is the mistake in the last lane :) MAybe im just dumb and I do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (it has so many uses besides filling heights)

```
.main_a {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:stretch;
}
```